# Input clone without value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in changing this script that goes to clone the input fields.

I would like to clone the fields without value, but I can not.

Can you give me any suggestions?
thanks

```
var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').length + 1;

    $('#addScnt').click(function() {
        if (i <= 10) {
                $('#p_scents p:first').clone().find('input').attr('name', function(index, value) {

                return value + i;
            }).end().append('<a href="#" class="remScnt"><%=xRimuovi%></a>').appendTo(scntDiv);

            new tcal({
                formname: 'NEW',
                controlname: 'startd' + i
            });

            i++;
            return false;
        }
        else {
            alert('Max element!');
        }
    });





<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="p_scnt" size="20" name="clienteNome_1" value="" placeholder="<%=xNome%>"  style="width:120px" />

<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="p_scntCon" size="20" name="clienteCognome_1" value="" placeholder="<%=xCognome%>"  style="width:120px" />

<input type="text" class="form-control"   id="p_scntMail" size="20" name="clienteMail_1" value="" placeholder="<%=xEmail%>" style="width:150px" onBlur="emailCheckemailStr(this.value)" /> 

<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="p_scntTel" size="20" name="clienteTel_1" value="" placeholder="<%=xCellulare2%>"  style="width:120px" />

  <input type="button" value="<%=xAggiungi%>" id="addScnt" class="btn btn-warning" style="width:100px;height:35px">
```

Comment: reset the value of the cloned element using the ```val()``` method.

Comment: FYI, IDs must be unique on document context. BTW, a `P` element should only contain phrasing element, not like inputs. You'd have better to provide in question all relevant HTML markup

Comment: How about `.find('input').val("").attr(...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the value to null after cloning. Try with -

```
$('#p_scents p:first').clone().find('input').val('').attr('name', function(index, value) {
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Set value blank after cloning

```
$('#p_scents p:first').clone().find('input').val("");
```

Comment: A paragraph has no value property

Comment: @A.Wolff... i missed that.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var field = $('input').clone();
field.val("");
```